# How can I persist enum type field, with Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have the following code

Repo

```
package my.taco.data;

import my.taco.models.Ingredient;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface  IngredientRepository extends CrudRepository <Ingredient,String> {
}
```

Controller

```
package my.taco.web;


import my.taco.data.IngredientRepository;
import my.taco.data.TacoRepository;
import my.taco.models.Ingredient;
import my.taco.models.Ingredient.Type;
import my.taco.models.Order;
import my.taco.models.Taco;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
@SessionAttributes("order")
public class DesignTacoController {

    private final IngredientRepository ingredientRepo;
    private TacoRepository designRepo;

    @Autowired
    public DesignTacoController(IngredientRepository ingredientRepo,TacoRepository designRepo){
        this.ingredientRepo=ingredientRepo;
        this.designRepo=designRepo;
    }

    @ModelAttribute(name="order")
    public Order order(){
        return new Order();
    }

    @ModelAttribute(name = "design")
    public Taco taco(){
        return new Taco();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String showDesignForm(Model model){
        List<Ingredient> ingredients= new ArrayList<>();
        ingredientRepo.findAll().forEach(i->ingredients.add(i));
        Type[] types=Ingredient.Type.values();
        for(Type type: types){
           model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),filterByType(ingredients,type));
        }
        return "design";
    }


    @PostMapping
    public String processDesign(@Valid Taco design, Errors errors,@ModelAttribute Order order){
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            return "design";
        }
        Taco saved=designRepo.save(design);
        order.addDesign(saved);

        return "redirect:/orders/current";
    }

    private List<Ingredient> filterByType(List<Ingredient> ingredients, Type type){

        return ingredients.stream()
                .filter(x->x.getType().equals(type))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Domain

```
package my.taco.models;


import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE,force = true)
@Entity
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final Type type;

    public enum Type{
        WRAP,PROTEIN,VEGGIES,CHEESE,SAUCE
    }
}
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Aplikacja Taco Cloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Przygotuj własne taco</h1>
    <img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}" class="img-thumbnail">

    <form method="POST" th:object="${design}">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="ingredient-group" id="wraps">
                <h3>Wybierz rodzaj mąki:</h3>
                <div th:each="ingredient: ${wrap}">
                    <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                    <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">SKŁADNIK</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient-group" id="proteins">
                <h3>Wybierz mięso:</h3>
                <div th:each="ingredient : ${protein}">
                    <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                    <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">SKŁADNIK</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient-group" id="cheeses">
                <h3>Wybierz sery:</h3>
                <div th:each="ingredient: ${cheese}">
                    <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                    <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">SKŁADNIK</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient-group" id="veggies">
                <h3>Wybierz warzywa</h3>
                <div th:each="ingredient: ${veggies}">
                    <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                    <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">SKŁADNIK</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ingredient-group" id="sauces">
                    <h3>Wybierz sosy</h3>
                    <div th:each="ingredient: ${sauce}">
                        <input type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                        <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">SKŁADNIK</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h3>Nadaj nazwę przygotowanemu taco:</h3>
            <button>Wyślij swoje zamówienie</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i go to /design i have the following error

```
Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
/error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Mar 14 00:28:34 CET 2021 There was an unexpected error
(type=Internal Server Error, status=500). could not execute query; SQL
[select ingredient0_.id as id1_0_, ingredient0_.name as name2_0_,
ingredient0_.type as type3_0_ from ingredient ingredient0_]; nested
exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute
query org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could
not execute query; SQL [select ingredient0_.id as id1_0_,
ingredient0_.name as name2_0_, ingredient0_.type as type3_0_ from
ingredient ingredient0_]; nested exception is
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query    
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:280)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
  at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
  at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
  at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.findAll(Unknown Source)   
  at my.taco.web.DesignTacoController.showDesignForm(DesignTacoController.java:49)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)     
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)     
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) 
Caused by:
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query    
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:52)
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2852)     
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2663)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2658)    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
  at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)   
  at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625)
  at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593)
  at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)  
  at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:356)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method)   
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:524)
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:156)
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
  at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
  ... 58 more 
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Błądkonwersji danych "WRAP" Data conversion error converting "WRAP" [22018-200]   
  at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:457)
  at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
  at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)     
  at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:875)  at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:737)  at org.h2.value.Value.getInt(Value.java:623)     at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getInt(JdbcResultSet.java:352)  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getInt(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
  at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:62)
  at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
  at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.convert.internal.OrdinalEnumValueConverter.readValue(OrdinalEnumValueConverter.java:66)
  at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:250)   
  at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:119)    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:91)     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3135)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1869)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1797)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1770)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1622)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:740)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1039)    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990)     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:959)  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2849)     ... 89 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "WRAP"
  at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
  at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)   at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)    at org.h2.value.Value.convertToInt(Value.java:982)   at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:806)  ... 110 more
```

Idk what`s wrong

schema.sql

```sql
create table if not exists Ingredient (id varchar(4) not null,
name varchar(40) not null, type varchar(10) not null);
```

data.sql

```
> delete from Taco_Order_Tacos; delete from Taco_Ingredients; delete
> from Taco; delete from Taco_Order;
> 
> delete from Ingredient;
> 
> insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
>                 values ('FLTO', 'Flour Tortilla', 'WRAP'); insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
>                 values ('COTO', 'Corn Tortilla', 'WRAP'); insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
>                 values ('GRBF', 'Ground Beef', 'PROTEIN'); insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
>                 values ('CARN', 'Carnitas', 'PROTEIN'); insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
>                 values ('TMTO', 'Diced Tomatoes', 'VEGGIES'); insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
>                 values ('LETC', 'Lettuce', 'VEGGIES'); insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
>                 values ('CHED', 'Cheddar', 'CHEESE'); insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
>                 values ('JACK', 'Monterrey Jack', 'CHEESE'); insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
>                 values ('SLSA', 'Salsa', 'SAUCE'); insert into Ingredient (id, name, type)
>                 values ('SRCR', 'Sour Cream', 'SAUCE');
```

Added data and schema for more details about problem.
type is varchar type so idk why i have number exception i dont have any number in my table

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` on your `type` field, like:

```java
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private final Type type;
```

This will allow persisting Enum field, as a string, in the corresponding varchar column.

`Ingredient` table's `type` column is of a varchar type, and `enum` needs to be represented as a String, in order to get mapped to that column.